# Using JQuery each with Wildcards

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

**Question**
Is there a way to split up each class based upon a prefix using JQuery each and Wildcards?

**EDIT:** In my case I want to split the elements by rel instead of class.

**Background**
Right now I am just generating a separate code block for each fancybox group which is a really big hack, but it works. I would like to pull this code out of the php class and put it on the html view, and only have it written once versus having a new block for each example_group. I am sure that there is a way, but for now I am stuck with my temporary hack.

**Current Code**

```
        (function($) {//use jquery each
            $("a[rel=example_group$group]").fancybox({
                'transitionIn'      : 'none',
                'transitionOut'     : 'none',
                'titlePosition'     : 'over',
                'cyclic'            : true,
                'titleFormat'       : function(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {
                    return 'Image ' + (currentIndex + 1) + ' / ' + currentArray.length + (title.length ? '   ' + title : '') + '';
                }
            });
        })(jQuery);
```

**SOLUTION**

```
        (function($) {
            $("a[rel^=example_group").fancybox({
                'transitionIn'      : 'none',
                'transitionOut'     : 'none',
                'titlePosition'     : 'over',
                'cyclic'            : true,
                'titleFormat'       : function(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {
                    return 'Image ' + (currentIndex + 1) + ' / ' + currentArray.length + (title.length ? '   ' + title : '') + '';
                }
            });
        })(jQuery);
```

Comment: Just to confirm, are you saying you want to select all `a` elements where the `rel` attribute *[starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)* `"example_group"`?

Comment: Yeah, you are correct. I am not sure why I said class, but all it required for me is to replace "a[rel" for ".". Thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('a[rel^="example_group"]');
```

This will target any anchor whose rel value begins with "example_group". That means, it will target all of the following:

```
<a ... rel="example_group1">Group 1</a>
<a ... rel="example_group2">Group 2</a>
<a ... rel="example_group_ponies">Ponies!</a>
```

For more information, check out the [Attribute Starts With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for. I only can contribute lack of sleep for the reason I couldn't figure it out...

Answer (score 1):

Done this many times before. That is if i got the question right :)

Well how i tend to do such thing is where you loop it out you add a class or id to the element. Such as if you have a slider. Then for the controls a typical html could look like:

```
<ul class="controls">
    <li class="control control-1" rel="1"></li>
    <li class="control control-2" rel="2"></li>
</ul>
```

That is typical for me at least. So let's say you're going to do something for every control there is. Easy as this:

```
$('ul.controls li.control').each(function () {
    console.log($(this).attr('rel'));
});
```

So what you do is you just group them up by having a additional class describing the current group. Then you have another class with a "-idhere" so you can target it directly and then finally the id of it using the rel.

-

Not quite sure i got the question right. But leave a comment on it and if i did't i will see if i have a solution :)

Comment: +1 this also worked for me, but I decided to go with Jonathan's solution.